# Custom UITableViewCell not updated even with setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I have been successfully subclassed UITableViewCell and I'm using the child class to layout some TableViewCell in my app. Now, I'm trying to lazy load images into the cells. According to logs, images download work fine however when it comes to update the images, nothing happens!

I've been trying:

```
// My custom class has a specific property for each subview in this cell. For example, 'thumb' is a UIImageView subclass to layout left image in each cell
cell.thumb.image = thumbdownloader.propertydata.thumb;
[cell.thumb setNeedsDisplay];
[cell.thumb setNeedsLayout];
[self.table_view reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

What is also suprising, I still see an old placeholder I've even removed from the project group...There must a caching somewhere but I don't have a clue about it!

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Comment: Yes...Only this caching is causing me pain lol

Comment: Do [tableview reloadInputView]; and also reload tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to reset your iOS simulator back to its original state, before you changed settings or 'installed' any apps on it.  In order to do this, open the simulator, and got to the iOS Simulator menu.  In the dropdown menu, there should be one listed 'Reset Content and Settings...', select that one.  If you are having a caching problem, this should clear everything from the simulator and start fresh.

Hope this helps!